# How to understand the result of adding a big float to a small double?

Tags: c, floating-point

when I write some C code like:

```
float f = 1.0e20;
double d = 1.0;
printf("%f", f + d);
```

The result f + d will still be the f value itself, I checked the CSAPP book, it says that because the expression f + d will be rounded to 1.0e20, but I do not know why it is rounded. The scale of float type value is far bigger than the 1.0e20, isn't it?

Can someone help me to understand this mechanism?

Comment: `float` is typically 32-bit and so able to encode about 2^32 different values.  The 67-bit integer value 100000000000000000001 is not one of them.

Comment: And the value you are printing is not really the same that is contained in the variable.

Comment: Before the addition is performed, `f` is promoted to type `double`.  Then the addition is done in double precision.  However, even in double precision, you get no more than 17 significant decimal digits in the result, so the addition of `1.0` will have no effect.  In other words, you're just printing `1.0e20`.

Comment: You can easily test this:  Try evaluating `1.0e20 + 1.0 == 1.0e20`.  The result will be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The scale of float…

The scale is irrelevant. The number of digits used in the significand matters.

A floating-point representation of a number has the form ±*d*.*ddd*…*ddd*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *b* is a fixed base, *e* is an exponent that scales the number, and *d*.*ddd*…*ddd* is a numeral in base *b* with a fixed number of digits.

In the format commonly used for `float`, *b* is 2 and *d*.*ddd*…*ddd* has 24 digits (which are bits because the numeral is in base 2).

In this format, 1e20 cannot be represented, because it would be +1.0101101011110001110101111000101101011000110001•2<sup>66</sup>, and that has 51 bits. When you write `float f = 1.0e20;` in source code, `f` typically ends up with the value +1.01011010111100011101100•2<sup>66</sup>, which has been rounded to 24 bits. (In decimal, this is 100000002004087734272.)

When you add one to this using real-number arithmetic, the result would be +1.010110101111000111011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001•2<sup>66</sup>, which again has too many bits. So the result is rounded. In `float`, this produces +1.01011010111100011101100•2<sup>66</sup>, which is the same value `f` started with. However, you used `f + d`, which uses a `double`, so `f` is also converted to `double`, and `double` arithmetic is used for the multiplication. But, even in `double`, +1.010110101111000111011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001•2<sup>66</sup> has too many bits. The format commonly used for `double` has 53 bits in the *d*.*ddd*…*ddd* part. So it is also rounded, to +1.01011010111100011101100000000000000000000000000000000•2<sup>66</sup>, which is the same value as +1.01011010111100011101100•2<sup>66</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the scale (range) of floating point types, it's the precision - that is, the number of significant decimal digits they can represent.  A single-precision `float` is not guaranteed to be able to represent more than 6 significant decimal digits, and a `double` is not guaranteed to be able to represent more than 10 significant decimal digits. `1.0e20 + 1.0` is

```
100000000000000000001.0
```

which is *way* more than 6 or 10 significant digits.

Here's a little program to demonstrate that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  float f = 1.0f;

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
  {
    printf( "i == %2zu, (1.0e%02zu) %15.2f + 1.0 == %15.2f\n", i, i, f, f + 1.0f );
    f *= 10;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and its output:

```
i ==  0, (1.0e00)            1.00 + 1.0 ==            2.00
i ==  1, (1.0e01)           10.00 + 1.0 ==           11.00
i ==  2, (1.0e02)          100.00 + 1.0 ==          101.00
i ==  3, (1.0e03)         1000.00 + 1.0 ==         1001.00
i ==  4, (1.0e04)        10000.00 + 1.0 ==        10001.00
i ==  5, (1.0e05)       100000.00 + 1.0 ==       100001.00
i ==  6, (1.0e06)      1000000.00 + 1.0 ==      1000001.00
i ==  7, (1.0e07)     10000000.00 + 1.0 ==     10000001.00
i ==  8, (1.0e08)    100000000.00 + 1.0 ==    100000000.00
i ==  9, (1.0e09)   1000000000.00 + 1.0 ==   1000000000.00
i == 10, (1.0e10)  10000000000.00 + 1.0 ==  10000000000.00
```

As you can see, once we start getting past 8 digits, the `+ 1.0` starts getting lost - the type just cannot represent that many significant decimal digits.